# Javascript - Automatically Set Field Value When Type on Field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date

i have form register using rails..
So basically I need to make feature that if you type ID on Field ID, it will be automatically

If you type in the ID field

- The first 4 digits directly (automatically) to generate to year
- The next 2 digits will be directly (automatically) to generate to month
- The next 2 digits will be directly (automatically) to  generate to date

i use datepicker for date field..
on _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id, "ID" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dob, "Date Of Birth (YY-MM-DD)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :dob %>
</div>
```

users.js.coffee

```
 jQuery ->
  $('#user_tanggallahir').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' })
```

i want type on field automatically of date..

**Update**

i have javascript such as http://jsfiddle.net/f8rUF/10/
but, i want format of date (dob) field such as 1990-01-12 (YY-MM-DD)

Hope you can help me with this ;)!

Comment: Have you tried handling the keyup event of the ID text field? Just automatically update the date field value.

Comment: @voithos i have handling the keyup event id text field to other field http://jsfiddle.net/f8rUF/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Solved..

i use substring to get 8 string

```
st = (v.substring(0,8))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8rUF/19/